# What is Maximum recording video size?

Tags: video-recording

i would like to use my smartphone to record my team soccer match. 
I've two question, one of those, a little off topics.

1. Our match length is 60 minutes. Do Android allows a 720p recording of 60 minutes ?
2. Is it possible to turn off display when recording ?
3. (a little off topic) I need a good solutions to 'append' my smartphone to a 'rounded' coverage (see photo).. i've tried to use tripod or 'car holder' ...but neither is a good solution. 
   Have you got some ideas ?

[image]